# Extracting the extension of a file

Tags: c, file, strtok

Some details

- Language: C
- System: Linux; working with command line (terminal),
  files are read in through the terminal
- User experience with C: 3
  months

I have been trying to extract the extension of a given file for example "myfile.wld", so that later I can make a check to see if the right type of file has been entered at the terminal before I work on the contents of the file. This is necessary for an assignment

I have used the function "strtok" to separate the input into sections by a delimiter "."

```
dot=strtok(argv[1], ".");
filename=dot;
```

filename is now the first part of the input "myfile", my question is how can I get to the second part after the ".", please advise, and please be patient enough to make it as simple as possible so that I can make use of your replies

Thanks

Comment: What if there's more than one "." in the filename?

Answer (score 3):

```
char *extension;
extension=strtok(NULL, ".");
```

after your code above.

First, call `strtok()` with pointer to `str` like this `strtok(str, ".")`.
Then keep calling `strtok(NULL, ".")` for next token.
When the returned value is null (`\0`) then it is end of string.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Basically you just need to call strtok again with a NULL pointer.  So:

```
filename = strtok(argv[1], ".");
fileext = strtok(NULL, ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

call `strtok` again passing in NULL as the parameter:

```
extension=strtok(NULL,".")
```

the first call to `strtok` should point to the string you want tokenized. All calls after that should have have NULL as the first parameter, `strtok` will return tokens until it has processed the entire string that was passed in during the first call

Answer (score 0):

The filename could contain more than one ".": **foo.bar.buz** for example. With your code you'll get **foo** and **bar.buz** instead of **foo.bar** and **buz** as expected. The right way is to use something like this:

```
char *filename = argv[1];
char *ext = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
if (ext) {
  *ext = '\0';
  ext++;
}
```