# File extensions in C as user input

Tags: c, file, strtok

I have a save as function and I need my program to recognise and separate the file name from the file extension. I have read 
[Extracting the extension of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935905/extracting-the-extension-of-a-file)
but my save as function is not main, so I can not have argv[1]. Here is my full code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void save_as()
{
    // user enters their desired name for the file
    char filename;
    char fileext;
    printf("Filename:\t");
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    filename = strtok(filename, "."); // according to the link I mentioned above this should have been: filename = strtok(argv[1], ".");
    fileext = strtok(NULL, ".");
}

int main()
{
    save_as();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strtok` takes a `char*`, but you declared `filename` to be a `char`, which is a single character.  In the other questions `argv[1]` is actually a `char*` (pointer to character string).

Answer (score 0):

Following lines are correct:

```
char filename;
char fileext;
printf("Filename:\t");
scanf("%s", &filename);
filename = strtok(filename, ".");
fileext = strtok(NULL, ".");
```

however `strtok` returns `char*` and you have declared `filename` and `fileext` as single `char`. Also note that there should be memory associated with the `filename` buffer. Change it to:

```
char filename[255];
printf("Filename:\t");
scanf("%254s", &filename);
filename = strtok(filename, ".");
char* fileext = strtok(NULL, ".");
```

Also consider checking the return value of these calls as some error might occur.

Comment: well, i changed filename and fileext to pointers, but now my program just crashes

Comment: @mee: Because the pointers were uninitialized. See my edit :)

Comment: sry, still crashes, though now it prompts me for the filename before crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can have argv[1]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void save_as(char *filename)
{
    // user enters their desired name for the file
    char *fileext;

    filename = strtok(filename, "."); // according to the question I mentioned above this should have been: filename = strtok(argv[1], ".");
    fileext = strtok(NULL, ".");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
       printf("usage: myprogram myfile.myextension");
       return 0;
    }
    save_as(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope, now it immediately crashes when i run it from my command line

Comment: You have to run your program `my_program my_file.my_extension`. I've edited the code in order to avoid the crash.